Auto-Py-To-Exe + Ursina, почему не сохраняються текстурки, модельки и звуки в файл .exe?
Я сначала запихнул все дополнительные файлы в папку assets (в проекте), импортировал папку в файл через additional files (Или как оно для папок называеться), не помогло. Поставил всё в 1 и ту-же папку что и скрипт игры, настроил скрипт, всё работает но не в .exe, даже когда добавляю файлы.

Ничего не понятно

Я когда импортирую все файлы проекта через additional files, ничего не работает, всё без текстур и моделек, (слава богу загружаеться Ursina), оно загружает все модельки и текстурки тогда, когда файлы игры находяться в 1 архиве или папке вместе с .exe файлом игры.

Значит путь к ресурсам у вас не верный..

Был бы он неверный, я бы тут не писал:/

Я и в скрипте и в импорте файлов указывал 1 и тот-же путь

А по текущим вводным вам больше ничего и не ответят

Что ты имеешь ввиду?

Имею ввиду вы ничего не показываете, но при этом спрашиваете почему не работает.. как ответить вам на такой вопрос? Ясновидящихтут нет.

А как я с мобилы перепешу скрипт в сообщение? Я же не за пк сейчас, теболее что показать?

Тогда ждите экстрасенсов, может кто и придёт ‍♀️

А что я показать должен то? Если ты не экстрасенс то я по твоему да? Ты скажи имеено что показать надо. Если скрипт, пожалуйста! Ты скажи что именно показать надо...

Покажите как путь к файлу получаете, как его добавляете, как его используете. Весь проект тащить не нужно, соберите максимально простой/упращенный пример который отражал бы вашу проблему. (Кнопка ПРАВИТЬ под вашей темой)

Я всегда просто пишу путь к файлу таким способом: Если в 1 папке, то просто название файла, если в разных папках (скрипт в папке выше чем то что импортируем), то пишу название папки/файл. А добавляю я из загрузок или других мест на пк откудого я эти текстурки и звуки скидывал, а модельки я просто с загрузок звпихнул в проект просто перетянув файл. На пайчарме ничего сложного в таком:/
